# How to render FluentUI controls in a HTML page similar to rendering React Components in a script tag inside a Div

Tags: reactjs, webpack, microsoft-teams, fluentui-react

I have a sample code for invoking a Teams Task Modules, where a typescript file is being render in a HTML page - github link for the sample : https://github.com/nanddeepn/code-samples/tree/master/MSTeams/task-modules-tab/YouTubePlayer_HTML_Page

There is a typescript file (https://github.com/nanddeepn/code-samples/blob/master/MSTeams/task-modules-tab/YouTubePlayer_HTML_Page/src/app/scripts/youTubePlayer1Tab/VideoSelectorTaskModule.tsx) and they are able to render the content inside a html page (https://github.com/nanddeepn/code-samples/blob/master/MSTeams/task-modules-tab/YouTubePlayer_HTML_Page/src/app/web/youTubePlayer1Tab/selector.html)
I couldn't understand how they are able to render the typescript in a HTML page.

My ultimate goal is to be able to render a typescript with FluentUI controls inside a HTML page so I could add to a Task Module with all the controls I need.
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please check out the following links - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8WVWirWYHE4, https://www.voitanos.io/blog/htwoo-microsoft-ux-alternative/, https://dev.to/maxprogramming/how-to-use-microsoft-fluent-ui-icons-on-your-website-1dff

Comment: Please check the following link to add fluent UI to HTML using CDN - https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/tree/master/packages/web-components#from-cdn

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below CDN link to render FluentUI controls in a HTML page - https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/tree/master/packages/web-components#from-cdn

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/@fluentui/web-components"></script>
  </head>
  <!-- ... -->
</html>
```